# Angularjs, using conditional tags (like ng-if) inside restricted tag (like select or table)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here is simple example of what i want to achieve:

```
<select>
      <option value="" selected>Default</option>
      <span ng-if="fld.has_opts1">
        <span ng-bind-html="fld.opts1"></span>
      </span>
      <span ng-if="fld.has_opts3">
        <option value="k" ng-repeat="k in fld.opts3">{{k}}</option>
      </span>
</select>
```

fld.opts1 is html string full of options:

```
fld.opts1 = '<option value="1">1</option><option .... </option>'
```

fld.opts1 is simple array:

```
fld.opts3 = ["peach","pineapple", ...];
```

Here i use `span` to specify condition, and this does not work because span is not allowed inside `select`, also i can't use `option` here, because this will be option nested in option and this is also invalid.

Actually i want it to be some invisible tag, like `<ng-if cond="fld.has_opts1">` which will disappear in final markup. How such kind of task should be currently solved in Angular ?

Comment: You're trying to insert additional options based on conditions, correct?

Comment: Can't you use the `ng-options` directive on the `select` element instead and loop on a filtered list of options according to your conditions?

Comment: can't you just use ng-show instead on an actual option?  Maybe explain what fld.opts1 contains?

Comment: You might be able to use the `comment` version of directives like `<!-- directive: ng-if exp -->` but I would not recommend it (see doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: Yes, i need to insert additional options based on conditions

Comment: The best solution would be to use `ng-options` with a custom `filter`. But we cannot help you more without your data.

Comment: It seems that `ng-options` is not enough here. `fld.opts1` contains html string full of options ("<option values="...</option>")

Comment: Where is `fld.opts1` coming from?  Can it be changed somewhere along the line?

Comment: @jpmorin: is there example of `comment` version of ng-if, bacause i have no idea how to express closing tag

Comment: It might not work with an `ng-if`.

Answer (score 1):

Using your own custom directive to append your html options in your select.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/6348/

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="fld.selected" my-html-options="fld.opts1" my-html-options-if="fld.has_opts1">
        <option my-option-is-html="false" value="" selected>Default</option>
        <option my-option-is-html="false" ng-if="fld.has_opts3" ng-repeat="k in fld.opts3" value="{{k}}">{{k}}</option>
    </select>

    Selected: {{fld.selected}}
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="fld.has_opts1" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.fld = {
        has_opts1: true,
        has_opts3: true,
        opts1: '<option value="Superhero">Superhero</option><option value="Superhero2">Superhero2</option>',
        opts3: ['apple', 'banana'],
        selected: ""
    };
}]);

myApp.directive('myHtmlOptions', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            myHtmlOptions: "=myHtmlOptions",
            myHtmlOptionsIf: "=myHtmlOptionsIf"  
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('myHtmlOptionsIf', function(newval, oldval) {
                if (scope.myHtmlOptionsIf) {
                    elem.append(scope.myHtmlOptions);
                } else {
                    angular.forEach(elem.children(), function(item) {
                        if (!angular.element(item).attr('my-option-is-html')) {
                            angular.element(item).remove();   
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you, but i consider custom directive as last resort, still hope for simpler solution

Comment: This is your best bet if you do not want to change your data format for opts1.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @jpmorin that a better approach would be to implement this in some way with `ng-options` and custom filters.  But the following should work.

```
<select>
      <option value="" selected>Default</option>
        <span ng-if="fld.has_opts1" ng-bind-html="fld.opts1"></span>
        <option value="k" ng-repeat="k in fld.opts3" ng-if="fld.has_opts3">{{k}}</option>
</select>
```

You can place your `ng-if` on the same line as the span that is doing `ng-bind-html`.

`ng-if` will just remove that span from the `DOM` it is different than an `ng-show` that only hides the element.